# Exploding number of homomorphisms

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, open-problem, db.databases, finite-model-theory

I'm trying to tackle the following problem: given two graphs $A$ and $B$, if there exists a graph $D$ such that $\hom(A, D) > \hom(B, D)$ (i.e. there is more homomorphisms from $A$ to $D$ than from $B$ to $D$), then for any $c > 0$ there is a graph $D_c$ such that $\hom(A, D_c) > c\cdot\hom(B, D_c)$.

The motivation for this comes from the query containment problem for the bag (multiset) semantics, [whose decidability is an open problem](https://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1087/keynote2slides.pdf). The antecedent of the implication is exactly the fact that $A$ is not contained in $B$ as conjunctive queries. The problem could be colloquially described with *if ever $A$ is bigger than $B$, then we can explode $A$ relatively to $B$*, hence the title.

I don't know if it is true in general, however, for any two $A$ and $B$ I could've thought, it is true. Also, there're some cases, where the problem can be easily proven, e.g. when $A$ has more vertices than $B$, or when there's no homomorphism from $B$ to $A$.

Do you know a solution to this problem? Or a counter-example? Or maybe any paper that may relate?

Comment: Can't you square $\mathrm{hom}(A,D)$ by taking the tensor product $D\times D$?

Comment: Or disjoint union of two copies of $D$

Comment: Indeed, the tensor product is the categorial product in the category of graph homomorphisms, hence it works.

Comment: @WeiZhan Yes, it seems like it is the case. Thanks.

Comment: @holf Unfortunately, it is not the case. Consider $A$ to be 1-2-3-4, and $B$ to be a 4-cycle. Then $A(A) = 16, B(A) = 14$, so we can take $D = A$. But for $D\sqcup\ldots\sqcup D$ the number of homomorphisms scales linearly for both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: indeed, I was too quick to answer!